# Using Path2D in a TypeScript project is not resolved

Tags: svg, typescript, definitelytyped, path-2d

I want to use the new [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) api in a TypeScript project but I don't see it in lib.es6.d.ts What is my best course of action to use this? Does anyone have a d.ts file for Path2D?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took me some time, and I made the Declaration for you:

I've done this following the same standard TypeScript defines its interfaces internally in `lib.d.ts`.
Note that you can extend this code easily for future features, and if you do I would love to see it updated here.

**Path2D.d.ts** ([View in TypeScript-Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F%2F%20Class%0Ainterface%20Path2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20addPath(path%3A%20Path2D%2C%20transform%3F%3A%20SVGMatrix)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20closePath()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20moveTo(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20lineTo(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bezierCurveTo(cp1x%3A%20number%2C%20cp1y%3A%20number%2C%20cp2x%3A%20number%2C%20cp2y%3A%20number%2C%20x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20quadraticCurveTo(cpx%3A%20number%2C%20cpy%3A%20number%2C%20x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20arc(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%2C%20radius%3A%20number%2C%20startAngle%3A%20number%2C%20endAngle%3A%20number%2C%20anticlockwise%3F%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20arcTo(x1%3A%20number%2C%20y1%3A%20number%2C%20x2%3A%20number%2C%20y2%3A%20number%2C%20radius%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*ellipse(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%2C%20radiusX%3A%20number%2C%20radiusY%3A%20number%2C%20rotation%3A%20number%2C%20startAngle%3A%20number%2C%20endAngle%3A%20number%2C%20anticlockwise%3F%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%3B*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20rect(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%2C%20w%3A%20number%2C%20h%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Constructor%0Ainterface%20Path2DConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20Path2D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(d%3A%20string)%3A%20Path2D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(path%3A%20Path2D%2C%20fillRule%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20Path2D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20prototype%3A%20Path2D%3B%0A%7D%0Adeclare%20var%20Path2D%3A%20Path2DConstructor%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Extend%20CanvasRenderingContext2D%0Ainterface%20CanvasRenderingContext2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fill(path%3A%20Path2D)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20stroke(path%3A%20Path2D)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clip(path%3A%20Path2D%2C%20fillRule%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D))

```js
// Class
interface Path2D {
    addPath(path: Path2D, transform?: SVGMatrix);
    closePath(): void;
    moveTo(x: number, y: number): void;
    lineTo(x: number, y: number): void;
    bezierCurveTo(cp1x: number, cp1y: number, cp2x: number, cp2y: number, x: number, y: number): void;
    quadraticCurveTo(cpx: number, cpy: number, x: number, y: number): void;
    arc(x: number, y: number, radius: number, startAngle: number, endAngle: number, anticlockwise?: boolean): void;
    arcTo(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number, radius: number): void;
    /*ellipse(x: number, y: number, radiusX: number, radiusY: number, rotation: number, startAngle: number, endAngle: number, anticlockwise?: boolean): void;*/
    rect(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number): void;
}

// Constructor
interface Path2DConstructor {
    new (): Path2D;
    new (d: string): Path2D;
    new (path: Path2D, fillRule?: string): Path2D;
    prototype: Path2D;
}
declare var Path2D: Path2DConstructor;

// Extend Window 
interface Window { Path2D: Path2DConstructor; }

// Extend CanvasRenderingContext2D
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D {
    fill(path: Path2D): void;
    stroke(path: Path2D): void;
    clip(path: Path2D, fillRule?: string): void;
}
```

Examples:

```
var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var path1 = new Path2D();
path1.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);

var path2 = new Path2D(path1);
path2.moveTo(220, 60);
path2.arc(170, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

var m = (<SVGSVGElement>document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")).createSVGMatrix();
m.a = 1; m.b = 0;
m.c = 0; m.d = 1;
m.e = 300; m.f = 0;
path2.addPath(path1, m);

ctx.stroke(path1);
ctx.fill(path2);
```

Comment: This is great stuff, perhaps this could be added to definitely typed.

Comment: For completeness I would add the following to the end of the file: interface Window { Path2D: Path2D; }

Comment: We should ping the guys over at d typed, or ts