# TypeScript Path2D class is missing a string constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, ionic2

I'm trying to create a Path2D object from an SVG string path. According to the [Path 2D documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) from Mozilla, it's possible to pass a string path as the parameter, however, when I try it in my code, the Webstorm IDE show me this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type "" is not assignable to parameter of type 'Path2D'
```

The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
let p = new Path2D('M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z');
```

I've found out that the lib.d.ts, where the Path2D is declared, does not have a string constructor for the Path2D class.

How can I solve this problem? I'm using Typescript 2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is open bug [Path2D missing string construtor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14660)

Wokraround is creating your own types

```
interface Path2DConstructor {
  new (): Path2D;
  new (d: string): Path2D;
  new (path: Path2D): Path2D;
  prototype: Path2D;
}
declare var Path2D: Path2DConstructor;

var p = new Path2D('M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z');
ctx.fill(p);
```

See also

- [Using Path2D in a TypeScript project is not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109921/using-path2d-in-a-typescript-project-is-not-resolved)

Comment: thank you, @yurzui. Where should I place this peace of code? I'm trying to include it in the lib.d.ts but unfortunately, I can't edit it.

Comment: You need to insert this code into the header of the file where you will use these definitions